# ServiceNow Attachment API REST call using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am currently developing a use case for a web application, where the architecture is defined in such a way that the frontend code picks up the attachment from the user's machine, is turned into the base64 format and sent to the backend code where the */api/now/attachment/file* will be used to insert the attachment to a newly created incident.

Now, I have a few questions over here:

1. What data format does the */api/now/attachment/file* accept? Is it binary? If so, how to convert a file into the required binary in Angular?
2. Is it possible to attach the document by converting it to base64 format and calling the */api/now/attachment/file* API? If so, how?
3. I am looking for implementation in TypeScript in the backend code similar to the post-
   https://www.servicenow.com/community/developer-articles/attachment-api-rest-call-using-java/ta-p/2329743

Please note that I can not use the scripted rest API examples that use inbound tables that are suggested in the different developer forums and the internet. I have gone through the product documentation pages of */api/now/attachment/file*. And lastly, I am not using any scripted API so no question about using the *setRequestBodyFromAttachment* function of **RESTMessageV2**.

I have also visited the following article which was quite similar to my query.
https://www.servicenow.com/community/developer-forum/what-s-raw-data-in-rest-attachment-api/m-p/1599915#M256841

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you let me know if you were able to resolve this? Thank you